# Stuck on the Gmail inbox

Tags: gmail

When I click on Gmail app, it takes me directly to my inbox. I cannot get out of it. I also cannot find my contacts, or the sign-in or sign-out page. I tried to uninstall it, but it would not let me.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

The Gmail app for Android is not the same as the gmail.com website.  You don't have to sign in when you open the app, because you already signed into your Google account as part of the initial setup procedure, when you first turned on your phone or tablet.

It's normal and expected for the Gmail app to take you directly to your inbox.  If you want to see other folders (such as your sent messages), tap where it says "Inbox" at the top of the screen — it's a drop-down menu.

Contacts are a separate app.  Look for "Contacts" or "People" in your list of app icons.